# Can I use the same envelope to email sign and embedded sign?

Tags: docusignapi

Can I use the same envelope to send email to some signers and even so allow embedded sign without email the others? I'm diggin' for a while and I can't find any info.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can mix Embedded and Remote signers in an envelope.

Each recipient that should be embedded should have a `ClientUserId` defined for them (so that the API recognizes them as an Embedded recipient). Any recipient without a `ClientUserId` defined will be a Remote (email) signer.